# setInterval() functionality for Axis in LightningCharts.js gets overridden?

Tags: javascript, lightningchart

Hi I am attempting to use LightningCharts.js for a particular Line Chart use case. The xAxis points are all Unix TimeStamp Epochs and the yAxis points are the actual target values which I wanna see over time.

This is the code snippet I use(data is the array which has the points)

`chart.getDefaultAxisX() .setTitle('Timestamp') .setTickStrategy(AxisTickStrategies.DateTime, ticks => ticks .setGreatTickStyle(emptyTick) .setFormattingSecond( undefined, { hour: 'numeric', minute: 'numeric', second: 'numeric', hour12: true }, (x) => 'minor' ) ) .setInterval({ start: data[0].x, end:data[data.length-1].x,stopAxisAfter:false}) .setScrollStrategy(AxisScrollStrategies.progressive)`

I was able to use the following code snippet to convert the timestamp to format time to look correctly however the issue i face is that the setInterval() functionality does not take the timestamp value range that I specify and my chart does not render correctly as a consequence(it is not fitted correctly as it shows from a range wider than the one i specify). I have tried using chart.getDefaultAxisX().fit() but it still doesn't work.

Is there a way to get the xAxis to be fitted automatically(only to the timestamp range which is specified) without using setInterval()

Any insight would be appreciated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So if I understood right, you want X axis to always be fitted to show all data?

Then you should remove `setScrollStrategy(AxisScrollStrategies.progressive)`. By default, axes have fitting scrolling, but that method call is changing that.

Also you should be able to remove call to `Axis.setInterval`, since as mentioned, by default axes to scroll to fit all data.

If it still doesn't work, there is probably some other issue in your code, which is not visible from the attached code in the question.